# PHP file get contents, re display images

Tags: php, fetch

Does anyone know how to get the following code to work? I get an error message when attempting to do so regarding DOM. I am attempting to re-display all images from a website that generates random images. In other words, extract images from a given URL, and re-display them. Asking this question in more detail, someone submitted the following, but I was unable to get it to work. Thanks much!

NOTE, this code below currently does not work, but gives an error message.  Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array in /home/wilsons888/public_html/wiki.php on line 11

```
<?php

 $html = 
file_get_contents("http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:Random/File");

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$image_src =  $xpath->query('//div[contains(@class,"fullImageLink")]/a/img')
[0]->getAttribute('src') ;
echo "<img src='$image_src'><br>";


?>
```

Comment: what is the error message? ***edit*** your question and put it in there!

Comment: remove that excess `}` at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you for the input Martin. @Martin. Unfortunately when I remove the } at the bottom, I get this error: 
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array in /home/wilsons888/public_html/wiki.php on line 11

Comment: the code you post on this Question then should be a minimum working verifiable example, but currently thats bad syntax with that `}` hanging around there!

Comment: Okay well, I'll clarify in description that this code isn't working. Do you have any advice for what needs to change to make it work? Since I get that error message.

Comment: I can't tell you much until you give details as to exactly what the error message is? See my first comment.

Comment: Sorry, I posted, perhaps it didn't go through.  
Unfortunately when I remove the } at the bottom, I get this error: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array in /home/wilsons888/public_html/wiki.php on line 11

Comment: just a note rather than solution - you don't need the closing `?>` if it's a php only file

Comment: I should clarify that the removal of the `}` *is only for the code on the question* NOT the code on your page. [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs didn't realize that, thank you

Comment: @Masteryogurt no worries :)

Comment: I'm still attempting to get this to work. If anyone knows of a solution, would be super grateful

Comment: it does work, but with openssl extension included

Comment: Possible to provide example of what that looks like? I'm going to start researching that now